# I seem to face this issue all of a sudden as this worked for a few weeks. Does anyone have a clue on what could cause this?

Tags: netty, webclient, reactor-netty

An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:624)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1463)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAddedForAllHandlers(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1115)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.invokeHandlerAddedIfNeeded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:502)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:417)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:474)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.handlerAdded() has thrown an exception; removed.
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:624)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1463)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAddedForAllHandlers(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1115)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.invokeHandlerAddedIfNeeded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:502)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:417)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:474)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.getContextOrDie(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1082)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:417)
at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.handlerAdded(PooledConnectionProvider.java:284)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:938)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:609)
... 15 common frames omitted

**Edit 1**

Thanks for the pointer. I see only below netty related things in dependency tree.
I am not sure which mismatch would cause the issue.

webclient app dependency tree
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  - io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.9.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     - io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        - io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.52.Final:compile

parent dependency tree

```
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:jar:2.10.91:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams-http:jar:2.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |        \- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:jar:2.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.54.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.54.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.54.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.54.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.54.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.54.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.54.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.54.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.54.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.54.Final:compile

[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.51.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.30.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:jar:2.10.91:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams-http:jar:2.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |        \- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:jar:2.0.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.53.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.53.Final:compile
```

Comment: Check that you do not have two Netty versions in the class path. Similar was discussed here https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor-netty?at=5f8f1e163d172d78b388f07a

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I see only below netty related things in dependency tree.  
I am not sure which mismatch would cause the issue. edited the original post with dependency tree

Comment: it might be the different version of the natives but for sure try to clean your class path

Answer (score 0):

@violeta

I am using spring boot 2.7.1 with the same version for webflux.
I am using spring native ( 0.12.0 ). I create a native image using packeto buildpacks on Windows machine (with ubuntu WSL)
The image is created and runs successfully in local.
However, when I deploy to ECS Fargate, I get the error mentioned above.

I have deployed spring-web native images in similar way, however there were no issues. I am not sure why would I get this error for spring-webflux.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32297989)